# Browsers only find RDP cert, not correct SSL cert

Tags: ssl, iis

On my local network, I have a Windows 10 machine with IIS and a tiny website. On the same network, I have a Server 2019 machine with Remote Desktop. My tiny website has an SSL certificate (from Let's Encrypt, not self-signed) bound to it and is listening on port 443. My gateway router has ports 80 and 443 forwarded to the Windows 10 IIS machine and the firewall has an incoming rule for those ports. Remote Desktop seems to have an expired certificate also, which doesn't bother remote desktop, but when I browse to my website, that expired RDP certificate is always the one that the browser finds, so the website is not trusted and not secure. If I test the website with any of several SSL testing tools online, those tools all find the correct certificate and the site is trusted and secure. I'm very reluctant to delete the old RDP cert, which might cause RDP to stop working.

I've deleted and remade the website, deleted and remade the cert, tried to change the port to 8080 and 8433, rebooted all machines several times, checked bindings, firewalls and port forwarding, and tested with every SSL tester I can find. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks, Lex Li, the site is https://www.freedomtrade101.com. However, I might have found a clue to the problem. I've been trying to load the Hello World page locally, from within my own network. I assumed the certificate would work OK locally, since IIS thinks it's fine, but maybe not. When I go to the site on my phone, no errors and the site shows secure. When I use a remote site tester, all is good and the site is secure. When I connect locally, I get the errors.

Comment: "when I browse to my website", and what's the exact URL? Keep in mind no one here can see your screen, so you need to provide enough details.

Comment: This issue may happens when the imported cert does not have a private key associated. solution would be to import the .CER file to your system(from where certificate is requested) personel store and export it with private key. Then copy the .pfx file to required server and import it from server certificate option under IIS.

Comment: I think accessing my site from within my own network was causing the cert to fail.